# Product of totally positive matrices is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This is a problem I encountered in my studies of matrix theory:

> We are given two symmetric real matrices, $ A,B $ , both of order $ n \times n $, and we are asked to show the following:
>
> 1. If all minors of $ A, B $  are non negative then so are all minors of the product $ AB $.
> 2. If all minors of $ A, B $  are positive then so are all minors of the product $ AB $.

Of course, this theorem stated more succinctly is "the product of totally-non negative matrices is totally-non negative". Now, I really do not know how to tackle this one, I thought maybe some determinant identity or matrix identity I am unfamiliar with is the clue. I thank all helpers.

Comment: is it not a trivial consequence of the matrix product operation column x line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both claims follow from the fact that each minor of $AB$ equals a sum of products of the form $\left(\text{a minor of }A\right) \cdot \left(\text{a minor of }B\right)$ (where, unlike the original poster, we allow $0 \times 0$-minors; note that a $0 \times 0$-minor is always equal to $1$ and therefore positive). This fact, in turn, follows from Corollary 7.182 in my [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf) (which is really just the Cauchy-Binet formula, with a superficial restriction on rows and columns). (The numbering might change in the future. If it does, look for Corollary 7.482 in the [frozen version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).)

The symmetry of the matrices $A$ and $B$ is a useless requirement.